# How to create label based on filename with reftex?

Tags: emacs, reftex

I'm using reftex under emacs. In my document, my label policy is the following :

```
\label{<buffer name>:<env>:<key>}
```

for example

```
\label{derivability:thm:Rolle}
```

Is there a way to do that automatically with reftex ?

Thanks you for any advice, link or documentation...

Answer (score 5):

`RefTeX customization` -> `RefTeX Label Support` -> `Reftex Defining Label Environments` -> `Reftex Label Alist`. Change `Label prefix string` (for every entry). Use `%f` for filename (extension will be stripped); for details, see the documentation in the customization buffer.

Comment: Doesn't work, since my reftex seems to ignore completly all customization. I have to check that...